# Refexp in Edit++: Find and replace where \n but no space before the "\n"

Tags: regex

I need a regexp that would find and replace the following in Edit++:

Replace all `\n` with the syntax `.\n`, but where there is no space before the `\n`. So all syntax `_\n` *(`_` means space here)* would be left intact. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Edit++, but I'd do it by searching for "([^ ])\n", and replacing with "$1.\n".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=[^\s]{1,1})\n|$
```

Demo [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=892f2e61-6853-43ac-b346-efcd35ea10c2).

Answer (score 0):

No idea about Edit++ but the regular expression should be to look for the absence of space (specified by `[^ ]` at the end of line (specified by `$`, and append `.`.  For example, in sed, the following takes care of it: `sed 's/[^ ]$/&./'`.